# Perl DBD::MySQL execute doesn't support string parameter after limit keyword. Always treated as number

Tags: mysql, perl, limit, quotes, sanitization

We recently set up a new OS with up-to-date DBI MySQL, Perl, etc.

This pattern in found several of our applications, and is breaking when installed on the new OS.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select null colname, null colname2 limit 0'
        . ' union all select x, y from tbl where col like ?'
        . ' union all select z, a from tbl2 where col like ?');
$sth->execute('%test%', '%test%') or die ...;
```

The error is a MySQL Syntax error.
We've identified the issue in the way parameters are quoted.

In the above example, it resolves like this at MySQL.

```
select null colname, null colname2 limit 0
union all select x, y from tbl where col like 
union all select z, a from tbl2 where col like
```

However, if `'%test%'` is swapped out with numbers (e.g. `'555'`), it comes through.

```
select null colname, null colname2 limit 0
union all select x, y from tbl where col like 555
union all select z, a from tbl2 where col like 555
```

Notice the absence of quotes.

We've identified this as being related to presence of the `limit` keyword. Removing the keyword solves the syntax error.

```
select null colname, null colname2
union all select x, y from tbl where col like '%test%'
union all select z, a from tbl2 where col like '%test%'
```

Also, setting `'555'` in Perl now results in `'555'` at MySQL, with quotes.

We found that using a derived table is the quickest way to resolve right now,

```
select * from (select null colname, null colname2 limit 0)a
union all select x, y from tbl where col like '%test%'
union all select z, a from tbl2 where col like '%test%'
```

(tried just parenthesis, but needed derived table to work) but I am curious if there's a way to control the quotation method through the DBI/DBD::MySQL interface instead. (avoiding an update to the statement)

Either change default behavior to disable the `limit` keyword logic
or, to force a particular parameter type as string?

Answer (score 5):

Parsing of commands containing LIMIT is buggy. Try [DBD::MariaDB](http://p3rl.org/DBD::MariaDB) instead which has hopefully already fixed the issue ([here](https://github.com/gooddata/DBD-MariaDB/pull/57/files)).

Answer (score 0):

Does your updated OS include a newer version of MySQL? The [documentation for UNION in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) says this:

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```

And this:

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
> ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
> ```

So I think you need to add some parentheses to your SQL.

Comment: I tried just parenthesis but somehow it didn't solve the problem like a derived table was doing.